# Rectangle having two lines inside it - find the ratio of the two lines.

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this problem? I used two similar triangles,PBM and MCQ, but it is very complicated. I wonder whether there is a simple way to solve the following problem. Thank you.

In rectangle ABCD, P and Q lie on AB and DC, respectively. ∠PMQ is a right angle, M is the midpoint of BC, and PB=4BC/3. What is the ratio PM:MQ? Express your answer as a common fraction.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint  Let $MB=x$ (which will divide out) and use the fact that $PBM$ and $MQC$ are similar-they are right triangles with the same acute angles.  Chase through using Pythagoras. Where are you stuck?